# SUM no SELECT com LEFT JOIN sendo multiplicados entre si

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Tenho 3 tabelas em MYSQL.

Conta:

```
id  nome

1   caio
2   zé
3   marcelo
```

Seguidores (o id da conta, ou seja, o usuário caio tem 2 seguidores):

```
idqual

1
1
2
2
2
3
```

Produtos (o id da conta, ou seja, o usuário caio tem 3 produtos):

```
idqual
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

O que tenho que fazer é uma consulta ordenando pelo numero de produtos que cada usuario tem e pelo número de seguidores que cada usuário tem, depois, tenho que listar quantos produtos e quandos seguidores cada usuario tem, achei que seria fácil fazer isso, e fiz assim:

```
SELECT conta.id, conta.nome, count(produtos.idqual) as somaprodutos, count(seguidores.idqual) as somaseguidores FROM conta 
LEFT JOIN produtos ON conta.id = produtos.idqual
LEFT JOIN seguidores ON conta.id = seguidores.idqual
GROUP BY conta.id, conta.nome
ORDER BY SUM(somaprodutos) DESC,
SUM(somaseguidores) DESC
```

O erro que ocorre é que o valor do somaseguidores e do domaprodutos está sendo o mesmo, e esse valor é sempre a multiplicação deles, exemplo:

Ele está dizendo que o usuário Caio tem 6 seguidores e 6 produtos (2 seguidores * 3 produtos), o que fiz de errado?

Comment: Me explica o sentido dessa divisão: `SUM(produtos.idqual/produtos.idqual)`?

Comment: Então, eu tinha q somar quantas vezes passa por cada produto, ai peguei o id do usuario (idqual) e dividi por ele mesmo, pra dar sempre 1, e ai vai somando 1 + 1 + 1, pra dar o numero de produtos que o usuario tem. Foi uma certa gambiarra....

Comment: Você pode usar a função `count()` para isso. =)

Comment: Opa, valeu, não conhecia, mas ele continua multiplicando o somaprodutos com o somaseguidores....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se ajuda:

```
        SELECT conta.id,
               conta.nome, 
               (select count(*) from produto where produto.idqual = conta.id) QtdProdutos,
               (select count(*) from seguidores where seguidores.idqual = conta.id) QtdSeguidores

        FROM conta

        GROUP BY  conta.id,
                  conta.nome

        ORDER BY QtdProdutos,QtdSeguidores
```

Comment: Assim está sempre dando 0, ele não encontra nada...

Comment: Opa IAGO, valeu pela ajuda, veja la que editei a minha pergunta, coloquei o count agora da forma correta e continua multiplicando os valores, estranho né?

Comment: você precisa agrupar pelo nome também

Comment: ainda assim, eles multiplicam... só fica certo ou os que não tem seguidores ou os que não tem produtos... exemplo, se um usuario tem 3 produtos e 0 seguidores o QtdProdutos da 3 e o QtdSeguidores 0....

Mas se o usuario tem seguidores e produtos, eles se multiplicam...

Comment: Opa, faltou o distinct, obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: caio, veja o edit

Comment: Opa, assim também foi certinho, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma pesquisada e vi que muitos usavam o distinct

```
count(distinct produtos.idqual) as somaprodutos
```

Fiz alguns testes e resolveu o meu problema!

```
SELECT conta.id, conta.nome, count(distinct produtos.idqual) as somaprodutos, count(distinct seguidores.idqual) as somaseguidores FROM conta 
LEFT JOIN produtos ON conta.id = produtos.idqual
LEFT JOIN seguidores ON conta.id = seguidores.idqual
GROUP BY conta.id, conta.nome
ORDER BY SUM(somaprodutos) DESC,
SUM(somaseguidores) DESC
```

Comment: Você me salvou um dia todo de trabalho, muito obrigado!